# Complex regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this task:
sum all numbers in string and perform multiplication

```
input: "3 chairs, 2 tables, 2*3 forks"
result: 11
```

I already have regular expression to do this:

```
eval(str.match(/(\d[\d\.\*]*)/g).join(' + '))
```

But I want to add option to ignore numbers inside brackets "()"

```
input: "2 chairs, 3 tables (1 broke)"
result: 5
```

How to do it?

Regular expressions were always pain for me :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way is to do a first pass and remove all parenthesized expressions.

```
str = str.replace(/\([^\)]*\)/g, "");
// now run your original algorithm to sum/multiply...
// ...
```

This is not super efficient but it does the job.

I should note that this does not handle nested parentheses, but it doesn't seem like that is required here.

Comment: +1, was about to add replace(/\(.*\)/,"") to previous answer but deleted it because you say same idea with a correct regex, taking into account its "greedy" nature

Comment: Cool. Thank you! I don't care about efficience, because string is short.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` to detect the out-most parenthesis so that you can get rid of what you want.This works with indefinite parenthesis

Comment: That fails on this expression: `"2 (not 3) and 3 (not 4)"`.  You would actually need a stack or something similar to keep track of the left parens seen so far, popping whenever you see a right paren.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=(\d+[\d.*]*)(?![^(]*?\)))\1
```

`(?=(` starts capturing a group using a look forward

```
(\d+[\d.*]*)
```

is the capture group for your number

```
(?![^(]*?\))
```

is a negative forward lookup that makes sure there isn't an open parenthesis after the number

```
)\1
```

look forward ends here match the found number.